# I had 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups' in django when I tried to save an user

Tags: python, django, forms, view, admin

I'm new in django, I have three groups in Admin: Medico, Paciente, Administrador. I just have the error, AttributeError at /registro/ 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups', but my form is saving all the data

```
# Registro del Sistema
def home_registro(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        formulario = PacienteFormulario(request.POST)
        if formulario.is_valid():
            paciente = formulario.save()
            grupo = Group.objects.get(name='Paciente')
            paciente.groups.add(grupo)
            return render(request, 'home/home_confirmacion.html')
    else:
        formulario = PacienteFormulario()
        context = {
            'formulario': formulario
        }
        return render(request, 'home/home_registro.html', context)
```

form.py:

```
class PacienteFormulario(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
            
    def save(self, commit = True):
        user = super().save(commit = False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        if commit:
            user.save()
```

Error:

```
line 35, in home_registro
    paciente.groups.add(grupo)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'groups'
```

I hope someone can help me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not return the user in the `save` method:

```
class PacienteFormulario(UserCreationForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2')
            
    def save(self, commit = True):
        user = super().save(commit = False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

But normally you do not need to override `save(…)` here, normally a `ModelForm` - and a `UserCreationForm` is a `ModelForm` - will handle this.

Comment: how the heck are you that quick

Comment: Thanks for replying extremely fast, yes it also works by removing save().

Comment: What is the use of save method, actually?

Comment: @technologyissuenepal: to save the user to the database. a `ModelForm` has a `save` method to create/update a record at the database. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method